# Windows client not receiving server Change Cipher Spec message at end of mutual TLS handshake

Tags: .net, windows, tls1.2, mutual-authentication

Windows .NET client app connects successfully to Java server and initiates TLSv1.2 handshake. Packet capture at server shows:

```
C>S Client Hello
S>C Server Hello, Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Certificate Request, Server Hello Done
C>S Certificate, Client Key Exchange, Certificate Verify, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
S>C Change Cipher Spec *FAILS HERE*
```

On server, no ACK is received for the Change Cipher Spec packet, resulting in multiple TCP retransmissions.

 On client, the application does not appear to receive this packet, the following exception is logged:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Stream transport, Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslClientAuthenticationOptions)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(String targetHost, X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, Boolean checkCertificateRevocation)
   ...
```

The server eventually times out the connection (set to 25 seconds). The rest of the handshake seems right: a shared cipher suite is selected, the client presents a valid certificate to the server, etc.

Why isn't the client reading and acknowledging this packet successfully?

Note: this was working about three months ago. Changes: the client renewed their client certificate (issued from same CA with same parameters)

We have validated that the client certificate is installed as expected, server is trusted, client and server have mutually supported cipher suites.

Comment: Possibly a misbehaving firewall/router?

Comment: Thanks! OpenSSL on the same server completes the handshake successfully -- I think that probably makes a perimeter firewall issue relatively unlikely. Could a Windows firewall interfere so late in the handshake?

Comment: Very possibly, although more likely in that case there is a cipher mismatch. Are both client and server machines' operating systems up to date? What cipher is it trying to change to?

Comment: We don't control the client side, so I cannot be sure as to OS updates. It is a .NET application running under Windows Server 2019. The negotiated Cipher Suite is: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028).

Comment: ECDH requires the latest Windows and .NET updates, you need some way of verifying that. Can you not test from a client you control? And run a Wireshark trace on that also?

Comment: We have no access to the server where the client application is running; it is operated by a different organization. ECDH was working 3 months ago with that system, but I will ask them about latest updates. There are thousands of instances of the same code running successfully on numerous a variety of other Windows servers as well as on our own Windows test systems. This is the only client site displaying this behavior.